# I am trying to install CLHEP 2.4.1.3 and I am stuck, getting an error in make install

Tags: 20.04, permissions, accessibility

Install the project...

```
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/bin/clhep-config
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "/usr/local/bin/clhep-config":
  Operation not permitted.
```

Comment: Did you run the install part with root permissions, i.e. `sudo make install`? If not, that can't work: Your normal user account does not have permissions to write to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: The install step (the command you omitted) is usually run as `root`, via the `sudo` command. Read `man sudo` and do something like `sudo cmake install`.

Comment: `Permission denied` and `Operation not permitted` are different errors - the latter is more likely the result of filesystem mount options or extended attributes (`chattr`) than simple file permissions imho